Tuxedo OS partitioning errors while installing on older laptop
I'm trying to install the latest verison of Tuxedo OS on an older laptop.  When I boot off the USB stick, everything works great; networking, video, sound, etc.  So it seems like it would be a good distro for this laptop.  However, when I go to actually partition the disk and install things, I run into errors.
Steps:

Click "Install TUXEDO OS" icon on desktop
Standard Installation
American English
Erase Disk: No swap, ext4
Enter login information
X11 standard installation

Partition information:
Erase disk /dev/md126 (md126) and install TUXEDO OS
Current: md126p1 300.00MiB FAT32
After: EFI system 300.00MiB FAT32

Creating new GPT partition table on /dev/md126 (md126)..
Create new 300MiB partition on /dev/md126
Set flags on 300MiB fat32 partition to boot
Create new 243902Mib partition on /dev/md126 (md126) with entries root
Set up new fat32 partition with mount point /boot/efi
Install TUXEDO OS on new ext4 system partition


Click "Install"

I get "Installation Failed"
Details:
Create a new partition (238.19GiB, ext4) on '/dev/md126'

Job: Create new partition on device '/dev/md126'

Command: sfdisk --force --append /dev/md126'

Failed to add partition 'New Partition' to device '/dev/md126'

Failed to add partition 'New Partition' to device '/dev/md126'

Any hints or tips on things I can try next.  Would love to get this OS working on this device, but my backup plan is probably to dig up an older distro of Ubuntu or something.
Thanks!

Hmm, I might have figured it out.  Not sure what causes the issue though.
Fix (For me anyway):

Go to the Terminal and run the command that failed:

sfdisk --force --append '/dev/md126'


Type write to commit the partition changes.

Run the installer again.

This time, I just select an existing partition to install on.


The installation worked this time, and rebooted and booted into the OS.
